# Error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol VS 6.0

Tags: c++

I was given access to the source code of an old video game. I don't know much about C++ but I am trying to compile the art tools that the game used. I've pointed it to the correct INC and LIB in the settings. This game was developed in Microsoft C++ 6.0. However, upon compiling the tools, I get this error. This is for a video game. And no it is not a dublicate.

```
LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib "LIBC" conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
Rbb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _MemDEBUGBlockTerm
Rbb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _MemDEBUGBlockFree
Rbb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CMDLineInit
Rbb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _MemDEBUGBlockInit
Rbb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _MemDEBUGSetFlags
Rbb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _FMGetTime
Rbb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _MemDEBUGBlockAllocLo
Rbb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ResBBIndexAdd
Rbb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ResBBTerm
Rbb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ResBBInit
Rbb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ResCalcChecksum
Rbb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _gResBBVar
Rbb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ResBBIndexFind
Rbb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ResBBResFixupRealloc
Rbb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ResBBIntFixupRealloc
Rbb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ResBBOutputRealloc
Rbb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _FMSeek
Rbb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _FMClose
rescomp.lib(ResTags.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _FMClose
Rbb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _FMWrite
rescomp.lib(ResTags.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _FMWrite
Rbb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _FMOpen
rescomp.lib(ResTags.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _FMOpen
rescomp.lib(ResComp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _RBFInit
rescomp.lib(ResComp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _RBFTerm
rescomp.lib(ResComp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _RBFEnd
rescomp.lib(ResComp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _RBFOutputF32
rescomp.lib(ResComp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _RBFOutputF64
rescomp.lib(ResComp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _RBFOutputSU128
rescomp.lib(ResComp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _RBFOutputSU64
rescomp.lib(ResComp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _RBFOutputSU32
rescomp.lib(ResComp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _RBFOutputSU16
rescomp.lib(ResComp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _RBFOutputSU8
rescomp.lib(ResComp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _RBFStart
rescomp.lib(ResComp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _RBFOutputAlign
rescomp.lib(ResComp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _gRBFVar
rescomp.lib(ResComp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _RBFLabelInstAdd
rescomp.lib(ResComp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _RBFLabelAdd
rescomp.lib(ResComp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _RBFOutputResourceFixup
rescomp.lib(ResComp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _RBFOutputString
rescomp.lib(ResComp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _RBFOutputNullString
rescomp.lib(ResTags.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _FMRead
rescomp.lib(ResTags.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _FMLength
PC\Win32\Debug/RBB.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 40 unresolved externals
```

Please be patient with me. I don't quite understand C++ just yet.

Comment: No, it's not.. Two different threads.

Comment: I see that the project consists of an executable and one (or more) dll(s). Did you correctly set the dependencies (the dll to be built before the exe), or if there are multiple dlls to build each dll's dependencies before itself?

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: This question was marked as a dup.